# Pytorch RNNLearner predict causes mem leak in docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pytorch, tensor, fast-ai

I am trying to run a simple predict with pre-trained model, but it keeps eating memory.

[ENV]

1. docker: docker Ubuntu18.04, python3.6 container
2. pytorch:
   https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
3. fastai: 1.0.46

this is the python code:

```
from fastai.basic_train import load_learner
predictor = load_learner(path, "file.pkl")
pred_class, pred_idx, outputs = predictor.predict("string")
```

I can not reproduce the memory leak on my mac or linux machine, so I think it is docker related problem, that maybe some missing library in docker or sth else. Any thought?